# Angular 5, 6 components communication using rxjs

Tags: angular

How do i get to pass, data around or call a function from one component to another in angular application 4, 5 or 6.
let's say i have my parent component with two or more component.

Comment: Best place to start is the [DOCS](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Answer (score 2):

the first thing here is to create a service component like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    constructor() { }

    private data = new BehaviorSubject<string>("Home");

    //this is what your components subsribes to
    currentData() : Observable<string> {
       return this.data.asObservable();
    }

    //this function allows you to change the value to be accessed by other components
    changeData(message: string) {
      this.data.next(message);
    }

}
```

this next step is setting your parent component to subscribe to the data service, as shown below.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    //component member variable to be changed on value change detection
    message = "";

    //here you'll inject in your component constructor the service declaration
    constructor(private data: DataService) {

    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.data.currentData().subscribe((message:string) => {
            //here i log changes detected on the console
            console.log("i have changed");
            //you can perform any call or action here e.g
            //update a variable
            this.message = message;
            //or call a function
            canCall();
        });
    }

    canCall(){
        console.log("i am called.");
    }
}
```

then after this every other components, can pass/change value and your parent component will pick up these changes and perform your logic.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './../data.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-productreview',
    templateUrl: './productreview.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./productreview.component.css']
})
export class ProductreviewComponent implements OnInit {

    //here we inject the data service just like before
    constructor(private data: DataService) { }

    //optional
    ngOnInit(){
        this.data.currentData().subscribe((message:string) => this.currentAction = message);
    }

    //this where we change the data
    changeData(option: string = "New Data"){
        this.data.changeData(option);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a service for that. The data in a service is shared among all the components. You can move all your data and functions to a specific service and call that service.
For example:

```
constructor(private myservice: MyService){};
```

.ts

```
this.myservice.myfunc();
this.myservice.mydata;
```

.html

```
{{myservice.mydata}}
```