# Is it better to communicate between parent/child components with RXJS or @input/@output

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have been looking around and have found that you can communicate with RXJS, for example this question explains how: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50967216/angular-5-6-components-communication-using-rxjs#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50967216/angular-5-6-components-communication-using-rxjs#_=_)
My question is what is the preferable way to communicate given the pattern of emitting (@output) and receiving events (@input)?
I should add that importing a service seems clunky as it binds you to that specific service but that may be just my limited understanding.

Comment: it's has no relation parent-child the only option it's use a service (but has no relation with Rxjs). Using a service you can do it sharing a data -using getter- or emit a value over an Subject or use next in an Observable. A getter are executed several times, so we must limited its use to a simple and fewers vriables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much easier and better to use input/output variables then rxjs observables in this case for these reasons:

1. With Input/Output you wont need to create a service and to inject it to both components.
2. There is no need to deal with subscribe/unsubscribe. Angular is doing it for you with input and output variables.

Notice that if you are dealing with sibling components, grandfather component or multiple state sharing then I would advice you to use state sharing with mutual service and behaviorSubject or even use a share manage pattern such as ngrx for more complex scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a parent-child relationship, you will always use events and inputs.
Use of information transfer via service will only be done if there is no connection between your components.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most preferable way is using Input/Output because this makes your component more general and not that tied up with specific implementation. Thus, you have an option to reuse it elsewhere just passing other property to the Input and using another handler with Output.

In general there is not that many difference of what you are using either service or Input/Output. Just different strategies for implementation for the same thing. However, usage of a service is more concrete and not "abstract" therefore if you need the same component in other context you would need to implement another component which uses another service.

IMHO, Input/Output is preferable in most cases.